# Application pane keeps crashing on startup in Domino Designer

Tags: windows, lotus-domino

Anyone know how I can reset it? Short of a re-install that is.

I've removed the offending database.

cache.ndk, desktop8.ndk, bookmarks.nsf

Domino Designer 9
Windows 8

Thanks!

/J

Answer (score 0):

I had source control enabled. Once I removed the on disk structure as well I could open the application pane fine.